Why won't Sphinx include my Ruby code examples?
I've got a .rst that has both Ruby and Python coding examples in it, but I am now in the position where I need to dyanimcally change the examples, so I'm setting the code example to an external file (which I can programmatically control) and then including it via directives in the .rst.
Without changes, everything works - that is, the Ruby and the Python code examples show up correctly in a code block.  But when I cut the code and paste it into an external file, only the Python code file gets sucked in.  The Ruby example is always blank.
I've tried 2 different ways (the first method is what I'm using for the external Python):
.. literalinclude:: myRubyFile.rb
  :language: ruby

where the .rb file is only Ruby code, and
.. include:: MyRubyFile.rb.rst

where the first three lines look something like this:
.. code-block:: ruby

  #Line 1 of code

Any ideas why Sphinx is handling the Ruby file poorly, but the Python file correctly?

You need at least two spaces of indentation for code under a code-block directive. I prefer 4 spaces, as that is the default for my editor.

I didn't get to set the format for our .rst files, but they all have one space under the code-block section and work fine.  For testing purposes: I changed my file to 2 spaces and it did not change the output:  Sphinx still ignores the file.

Ugh.  Much like "RTFM", one also needs to "RTFL".
WARNING: Encoding utf-8-sig used for reading included file <filename> seems to be wrong.  So I've got a "bad character".  There's always one character...

Answer:  Save your file as the default Sphinx file format = UTF-8 with BOM.
Also:  read your logs before you post a question. 
